# opening new content view

Tags: java, android

In my `Main.class` I am creating a dynamic `ScrollView` and starting it using `setContentView(sv)` it displays a `Spinner` and a `Button`.

The user selects an option from the `Spinner` and then clicks the `Button`. I have set a  `setOnClickListener` to the `Button`.

In the `onClick` method I am trying to start up a new `ContentView`. Calling a new class file with the same type of layout as `Main.class`. Not sure how to go about doing this. I added `finish()` to the `onClick` method and it closes the original window but not sure how to open the new one.

Here is the `Main.class` code:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.messages = new Messages(this);
    this.datasource = new FacilitiesDataSource(this);
    this.datasource.open();

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);     

    Spinner s = new Spinner(this);
    s.setId(SPINNER_FACILITIES);
    s.setLayoutParams(new Spinner.LayoutParams(-2,-1));
    final List<SpinnerObject> list = this.datasource.getFacilitiesList();
    final ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerObject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    ll.addView(s);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Submit");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(-2,-1));
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(SPINNER_FACILITIES);
            Log.v("option picked",  Integer.toString(( (SpinnerObject) spin.getSelectedItem () ).getId () ));
            /*
             * NEED HELP HERE 
             * NEED HELP HERE 
             * NEED HELP HERE 
             */
            //finish();
        }

    });
    ll.addView(b);
    setContentView(sv);
}
```

Here is my `Vehicles.class`:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("Started onCreate", "Vehicle");
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    setContentView(sv);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html
Check out the fundamentals of Android development...
And look at startActivity() ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent) ) and Intents (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to start a new `Activity` (from `Main` to `Vehicles`). In that case you can use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Vehicle.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure all `Activity` classes are declared in your `Android Manifest` file, inside the `<application>` tag, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Vehicles" />
```